# Powering an opamp via Zeners

Tags: operational-amplifier, zener

[image: ada4084-2]
[ada4084-2 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ada4084-2.html)

According to datasheet:
"Supply Current per Amplifier": 0.625 mA .

The maximum total power consumption would be 1.25 mA.

[image]

I want to scale the +/- 12 volt power supply down by a Zener.

Would one do this? I only need to power one opamp package.

Comment: 0.625 mA quiescent current doesn't include opamp *output current*. If you drive current into a load, or have to charge (discharge) capacitance with an AC signal, more current must flow from \$\pm\$ supplies.

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way, least not of all to drive an op-amp. Your noise immunity and line/load regulation will all be pretty bad, not to mention that efficiency is pretty poor. Why are you avoiding the use of small linear regulators (like 7805 and 7905)?

Comment: @glen_geek, well the lm4040's seam to offer up to 15mA thay should be enough, not? at max i need force 0.12 mA through a patch cable to the next part, no voltage follower configuration needed behind the ada4084?

Comment: @NaturalDemon an LM4040 does not "offer up" any current at all. All of the current sourced or sunk in a simple zener regulator type circuit like those goes through the series resistors (your R19 & R21). You can get 78L05 regulators in the same package as an LM4040, so you're not saving any space here...

Comment: @BrianB just an idea, smaller pcb area, couldn't find a smd version for 78l.. and 79L.. in eagle.

Comment: Before you ask a question like these, you need to tell us all your assumptions , like wasted power, load device, supply available, cost, space, Eagle and the reason why you need to do what you asked for. There may be far better ways.  Zenere's are ancient solutions unless you must limit the output for some unknown reason

Comment: "Force 0.12 mA through a patch cable" - if that patch cable happens to be 100M of [RG58 co-ax](https://www.pasternack.com/images/ProductPDF/RG58C-U.pdf) with 101.5pF/M parasitic capacitance, that 120µA (implied V=12V, Z=100k) will struggle against the 0.1015µF: \$\tau\ = 100k\cdot 0.1015µF = 10.15\$ms for 63% of an input change to appear at the other end of the cable... limiting frequency to \$\dfrac{1}{10.15ms}=98.5\$Hz.  (Ignoring cable inductance.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schematic design is just fine providing you don't want high current output.

At +/-5 V for the AD4084 you need to provide +17 mA and -24 mA if you want the supply to remain at +/-5 V while the output is shorted.
If your load current is much less than the Isc rating, then the supply voltage will collapse under short circuit condition. Since this is self protecting it's quite reasonable to do this.

Since the [LM4040B50](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4040.pdf) has a minimum current requirement (Iz) of about 100 uA your maximum output load is about +/-8.3 mA before pulling the supplies out of regulation.
[image]

While a shunt regulator draws a constant current it is also self protecting (short circuit proof). You could use a linear regulator (78L05 and 79L05), but these would provide higher noise floors and less accurate supplies (if that is important). The linear supplies also have an Iq of 5-6 mA, so the power saving would be almost non existent.

Comment: thanks for you reply, AD4084 is an expensive part compared to an Tl072, i have to do it right. i'll probably choose for voltage regulators, now the question remains since a (synth) patch cable max output is about 0.12 mA AC ( 12 Volt / 100 +1 kOhm), should i add a voltage follower behind the ADA4084-2 to offer protection.

Comment: You should always provide short circuit protection for output cable systems. You have the ability to provide that by changing R19 and R21. I would not provide buffering, but simply set the short circuit value to that appropriate to your application and go with the LM4040B50.

Comment: pretty much every synthesizer module has a 1K resistor between opamp and output jack as short circuit protection, since most module are made of aluminum and the tip of the cable hits GND on a regular base.

i'm just wondering if the AD4084 can offer what the TL072 normally can offer. currently the AD4084 is the last ic before the output jack.

Comment: http://www.calculatoredge.com/electronics/zener.htm, it seams i need to use 200 Ohm for 12V.

Comment: I would not go below 350 Ohms (about 10 mA current). That gives you a maximum short circuit of about 20 mA at the +/-5 V rail and probably about +/- 8 mA at the op-amp output.

Comment: Thank you again, i'll set it 350 Ohm ... this is my first attempt to design a pcb and outsource it, it has to be right.